# Copy SVN repository to remote location without using disk space locally

Tags: svn, backup

I want to copy a svn repository to a remote location.
The server that I have the svn repository on has very limited disk space, so I can't store a **local** copy of the repository.

Is it possible to for example make a hotcopy (svnadmin hotcopy) and send it over "on-the-fly" to the remote location?

The documentation says:

```
svnadmin hotcopy REPOS_PATH NEW_REPOS_PATH
```

I am thinking about if the NEW_REPOS_PATH can somehow be a remote location.

Comment: Did you give it a try? In theory it should work. Just use the UNC path  for your new location. \\server\repo\new_repoBackup

Comment: See this question on Server Fault: [how to backup svn remotely without a local copy](http://serverfault.com/questions/363594/how-to-backup-svn-remotely-without-a-local-copy)